# CSS - Background image doesn't show up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background image to my page but it doesn't show up. Could someone help me out please ?

```
.body{
background-image: url('file:///C:\Users\kaspe\Desktop\Website\backgrund.jpg');}
```

Comment: Use `/` in your url, not `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the 'body' HTML tag so you don't need the dot '.'.

The dot is used for CSS classes.

Try:

```
body {
    background-image: url('file:///C:\Users\kaspe\Desktop\Website\backgrund.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to give it a full path. just  give the foldername/imagename. I assume website is your folder name where you put your image. Try to put it not instead of your code. Moreover add background-size: cover; to show image with full screen.

```
body {
    background-image: url('Website/backgrund.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```